# Wordpress archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

I want more functionality out of the wp_get_archives tag. I want my results to look like this:

Year

Month

Post
Post
Post

Year

Month

Post
Post
Post

To achieve this, am I going to have to use the loop? Is there another way to do this besides the loop?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, to do this, you'll be writing your own logic in the archive page using the loop.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of [archives related plugins][1] that do close to what you want.

[1]: [WordPress › WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=archives)